# How could we associate a medical image's segment position, to the click's event position in JS?

Tags: javascript

**Hello and thank you for reading me!**

This question is heavily related to this library: https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami

*I would like to create a function to detect if you have pressed in a image's segment, to be able to display a dialog with a message that informs about it.*

By myself, and looking for examples in StackOverflow, I have made the basics to detect if you have pressed and where, and by a condition distinguish if you clicked near a segment or not:

```
window.addEventListener('click', onWindowClick, false);

    function onWindowClick(event) {
        if (event.clientX > 200 && event.clientX < 300) {
            alert('You have clicked: ' + event.clientX + " " + event.clientY + ' on the segment');
        } else {
            alert('You have clicked: ' + event.clientX + " " + event.clientY + ' out of the segment');
        }
```

An example output, if you click near the green region:
[image]

If you click outside:
[image]

The issue is: ***what data/position/resource do I have to be able to compare the current clicked position and assert that you clicked in or out?***

Well, by myself I have examined the data structure, and it looks like there are two options. First, we could use the frame's position, which looks like it represent the segmentation's spatial position, and it looks like:
[image]

Where clicked pos is: `277 294`
and _imagePosition from data structure is: `-201 -59`

Also, another alternative is the stack's origin:
[image]

Here the clicked pos is: `278 301`
and the origin is: `-201 -59`

So then it looks like whether I choose _imagePosition or origin I would need to do some conversion.

I do have studied that are used an ijk and lps coordinate systems, and in the lessons and examples is common to see a matrix which is updated to convert between them.

Do you have any suggestions or help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by "image segment" but I assume you mean you are trying to see if the user clicked or not on the image.

You should use the THREEJS Raycaster (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster) and see if it intersects the "slice mesh".

That is what we do in the quadview example when you double click in one of the 2D viewers: https://fnndsc.github.io/ami/#viewers_quadview

Relevant code:

```
function onDoubleClick(event) {
  const canvas = event.target.parentElement;
  const mouse = {
    x: ((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / canvas.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
    y: - ((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / canvas.clientHeight) * 2 + 1,
  };
  ...
  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    const lpsCoordinates = intersects[0].point;
    const ijkCoordinates = CoreUtils.worldToData(lps);
  }
```

Source code:https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami/blob/dev/examples/viewers_quadview/viewers_quadview.js#L564-L617

Comment: Hello Nicolas and thank you for your fast and good reply. By image segment I was refering to the label map. I mean, I would like to not only detect if the user clicks on the slice but to detect that the click was on the label map. I have studied the example you provide and it would be a first step to filter out clicks on the background, however is not exactly the full answer. Thank you!